# Kivy - How to make a initialized object refresh in the screen?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, frontend, kivy-language

I am making an eBook reading app by Kivy :)
But when I try to make a screen generating a list of buttons according to the API responses, there has some issue - the Boxlayout object won't refresh after i change the parameter.

The idea is that every time user search the article will renew the app.article_id_list attribute. And I need the ArticleTitleList(BoxLayout) object refresh itself with new article_id_list while user enter the ArticleTitleWindow(Screen).

What is the correct way to do this,give me some hint please !

my python file :

```
class ArticleTitleWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(ArticleTitleWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.on_enter()

    def on_enter(self):

        return ArticleTitleList()


    def search_ListID(self):

        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.article_id_list = (self.ids.search_ListID_input.text)
        self.ids.search_syntax_input.text = ""



class ArticleTitleList(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        
        app = App.get_running_app()

        print("initialized new ArticleTitleList")
        print(app.article_id_list)
        print("initialized new ArticleTitleList")
        
        for Article_IDs in app.article_id_list:

            Article_Titles, Article_Contents = Get_article_title_content_by_article_id(Article_IDs)

            ArticleTitle_Button = Button(
                text=str(Article_Titles),
                size_hint_y = None, # To set custom value.
                height = dp(100),
                font_name = "msyhl.ttc",
                font_size = 24, # Specify height of the widget explicitly.
            )

            ArticleTitle_Button.article_id = Article_IDs
            ArticleTitle_Button.article_title = Article_Titles
            ArticleTitle_Button.article_content = Article_Contents

            ArticleTitle_Button.bind(on_press= self.MoveTo_Article_Press)
            ArticleTitle_Button.bind(on_release= self.MoveTo_Article_Release)
            

            self.add_widget(ArticleTitle_Button)
    


    def MoveTo_Article_Press(self, instance):

        app = App.get_running_app()

        app.ArticleID = instance.article_id
        app.ArticleTitle = instance.article_title
        app.ArticleContent = instance.article_content


    def MoveTo_Article_Release(self, instance):

        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.root.current = "Article"

class MyApp(App):

    article_id_list = ListProperty([])

    ArticleID = NumericProperty(1)
    ArticleTitle = StringProperty("Default Title")
    ArticleContent = StringProperty("Default Content")

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string(kv_string)
        return kv
```

my kivy string :

```
WindowManager:
    HomepageWindow:
    ArticleCatagoryWindow:
    ArticleTitleWindow:
    ArticleWindow:
    AuthorWindow:


<ArticleTitleWindow>:
    name: "ArticleTitle"

    GridLayout:

        cols:1
    
        GridLayout :
            size_hint: (1, 0.07)
            cols:2
      
            TextInput:
                id: search_syntax_input
                multinline:False
                font_size: 24
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"


            Button: 
                size_hint: (0.2, 0.07)
                text: "Search"
                font_name: "msyhl.ttc"

                font_size: 18

                on_press:
                    root.search_syntax()

                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "ArticleTitle"

        ScrollView:
            cols: 1
            size_hint: (1, 0.93)

            ArticleTitleList:

                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
```

Comment: The line of code `return ArticleTitleList()` in your `on_enter()` method has no effect. It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks your kindly remind John!
I want to refresh my ArticleTitleList object by doing that. 
It help me reinitialize the object with new attribute value( which  [print(app.article_id_list))] will be execute while enter that screen) 
thats the idea. but some how the newly initialized object won't refreshing on the front end :(

Comment: The idea is that every time user search the article will renew the app.article_id_list attribute. And I need the ArticleTitleList(BoxLayout) object refresh itself simultaneously to show user a new article list in ArticleTitleWindow(Screen).